# PHP Santizing/Validating Array of Integers

Tags: php, arrays, validation, integer, sanitization

I have the following array and would like to know what the best way would be of validating and santizing this array to make sure **only integers** are allowed?

```
if(is_array($_POST['taxonomy'])) {
    $term_ids = array_map('esc_attr', $_POST['taxonomy']);
}
```

Which looks like this when printed:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 12
)
```

I know the esc_attr isn't very secure so would like something a bit more beefed up.

Any help would be great.

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: Cast them to INTs no matter what...

Comment: If it was a string I'd just use (int) but is there something similar to use for an array? Thanks for your reply

Comment: you do that for array values on loop

Comment: Just cast them and map them to ints.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since it's `$_POST` data, you'll want to check for [`ctype_digit`](http://www.php.net/ctype_digit) (i.e. a string containing only digits):

```
$sanitizedValues = array_filter($_POST['taxonomy'], 'ctype_digit');
```

Note that this simply discards non-numeric values.

Comment: just tried this and it seems to be working spot on, thanks for everyone elses comments by the way, very helpful! How secure is this though? If someone were to inject something into this array? (We've had a few issues with hacking hence I'm going through all the code and plugging any holes). Cheers

Comment: With this you can be sure that `$sanitizedValues` contains only strings that contain only numbers. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Very nice, and very clean. Cheers @deceze and everyone else who posted a reply.

Comment: Nice. Exactly what I was looking for. Kudos.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative would be using phps [filter](http://www.php.net/manual/ref.filter.php) functions:

```
$array = array(
  13, 12, '1', 'a'
);

$result = filter_var($array, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
  'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
  'options' => array('min_range' => 1)
));

var_dump($result);

/*
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(13)
  [1]=>
  int(12)
  [2]=>
  int(1)
  [3]=>
  bool(false)
}
*/
```

Comment: Much more verbose but technically more appropriate. +1 :)

Comment: Sorry guys, whats the difference between the two?

Comment: If it's a single field you're validating, I think it's just a matter of taste. Although if you have a lot of validating the filter functions can save you some work (see [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/function.filter-input-array.php) for example). And I guess, if you or someone else has to understand what you're doing 3months later, the filter function do more clearly show whats happening.

Comment: At the moment its just a single input. I've checked out the filter_input_array and it looks like its going to be very useful! I'll +1 this answer also, thanks alot @Yoshi for your help and advice. Every day's a school day :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = (int) $value;

    if( $array[$key] != $value ) {
        // error
    }
}
```

Comment: POST data is never `int`, it's all strings.

Comment: This looks like numbers:

Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 12
)

Comment: Yes, but they're *strings*, not `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(is_array($_POST['taxonomy'])) {
    $term_ids = array_map('intval', $_POST['taxonomy']);
}
```

Should do the trick. NOTE: this is sanitation. More: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for one-liner to check against specified condition you can use:

```php
$onlyIntegers = Arr::check($_POST['taxonomy'], 'ctype_digit');
```

assuming your `$_POST['taxonomy']` can contain numeric strings as @deceze suggested, or just plain:

```php
$onlyIntegers = Arr::check($_POST['taxonomy'], 'is_int');
```

if you are sure that `$_POST['taxonomy']` values should be in fact integers.

`Arr::check` method is a part of this [php array library](https://packagist.org/packages/minwork/array) which contains various methods to help you deal with different types of arrays.